# RenderPartial, model as argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I get a type error but I don't understand why, I have a View, a ViewModel, a PartialView and a Model.

The view gift has giftViewModel as model.
giftViewModel contain an instance of the Model LoginModel (login).

The partialView LoginPopUp takes a LoginModel as model.
I try to render the partialView LoginPopUp within the gift view, passing it login as model.

And I get this error :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'GiftViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'LoginModel'.
```

Here is the code:

GiftViewModel.cs

```
    public class GiftViewModel
{

    public LoginModel login { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Gift/Index.cshtml

```
@model GiftViewModel

@section content{

  @{Html.RenderPartial("LoginPopUp", Model.login);}
}
```

LoginPupUp.cshtml

```
@model LoginModel
[...]
```

I really don't understand where I am wrong...

Comment: Make sure that `Model.login != null` in the `@{Html.RenderPartial("LoginPopUp", Model.login);}`.

Comment: Thank you it was the case ! For my defense, the error message was very puzzling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check whether `Model.login != null` in the line

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("LoginPopUp", Model.login);}
```

In case it is equal, the framework will pass model form the parent view to the `LoginPopUp`, which is type of `GiftViewModel`. That is why you are getting this error, because the partial view requires a model item of type `LoginModel`.

So either initialize the `login` property before that, say in controller, or do something like

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("LoginPopUp", Model.login ?? new LoginModel());}
```

Comment: I usually initialize such 'sub' models in the constructor of the model  to avoid such errors and `NullReferenceException`s.